# TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function only when jest runs tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, jestjs

In my node js project I have a firebase.js file which connects to the real-time database and exports a few functions that have to do with my users data.

firebase.js

```
'use strict'

const firebase = require('firebase')

const config = {
    apiKey: 'xxx',
    authDomain: 'xxx',
    databaseURL: 'xxx',
    projectId: 'xxx',
    storageBucket: 'xxx',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxx'
} 

firebase.initializeApp(config)

const db = firebase.database()

module.exports.getUserByUid = async user => {
    const usersRef = db.ref(`users/${user.uid}`)
    const snapshot = await usersRef.once('value')

    let userToReturn

    if(snapshot.exists()) {
        userToReturn = snapshot.val()
        userToReturn.uid = snapshot.key
    } else {
        throw Error('user not found')
    }

    return userToReturn
}
```

I am calling this from a userProcessor.js file

userProcessor.js

```
const db = require('../database/firebase')

module.exports.getUserByUid = async request => {
    const user = await this.extractUserData(request)
    const userToReturn = await db.getUserByUid(user) //here
    return userToReturn
}
..
module.exports.extractUserData = request => ({
    uid: request.body.uid,
    username: request.body.username,
    email: request.body.email})
```

If I call this from a file directly it works.

I am using `koa` to expose this to a `GET` request on a web api and it works fine (tested with Postman).

But when I try to run my jester tests on it it throws:

```
TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function

      15 | }
      16 | 
    > 17 | firebase.initializeApp(config)
         |          ^
```

userProcessor.test.js

```
const userProcessor = require('../modules/processors/userProcessor')

test('retrieve user that does not exist', async done => {
        try {
            await userProcessor.getUserByUid({body: {uid: '99xa999axa9x9x'}})
        } catch(err) {
            expect(err.message).toBe('user not found')
            done()
        }
    })
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.11.0",
    "firebase": "^5.5.8",
    "jest": "^23.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^6.1.0",
    "http-status-codes": "^1.3.0",
    "koa": "^2.6.2",
    "koa-bodyparser": "^4.2.1",
    "koa-cors": "0.0.16",
    "koa-router": "^7.4.0",
    "supertest": "^3.3.0"
  }
```

Comment: Don't you need to use `firebase-functions-test` to enable remote testing?

Comment: I have tried very similar (if not identical) code before and it worked, all the tests went on the database but I changed something (I think) and it throws that error. I have to use jest as it is a requirement but do you think that maybe firebase blocks my requests because I dont use `firebase-functions-test`? @RandyCasburn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I had a folder called `__mocks__` in the same folder with `firebase.js` which contained another file called `firebase.js`.

The solution was changing

```
const firebase = require('firebase')
```

to

```
const firebase = require('../../node_modules/firebase')
```

Comment: How could someone else had known that you had kept a local file with same name as of module.

Comment: It was not in the same folder as the file requiring the module. It was in a folder called `__mocks__`. I am new to javascript and node js and I did not expect it to point to that mock file unless specified the full path e.g.: `require('__mocks__/firebase')`. I did not blame anyone for not having the answer and I just let everyone know what the issue was, don't be a jerk

Comment: I didn't wanted to offend you and that's nice of you to post solution. I just wanted to bring this into your notice that if someone else had same error as `TypeError: firebase.initializeApp is not a function` due to some other error like version of installation and came here looking for answers they will be miss leaded. In these cases post must be deleted so other won't get misguided.

Comment: Since jest's convention of mocking is to place a file with the exact same name in a folder called `__mocks__` at the same level of the file to-be-mocked and since firebase database is a layer one would might want to mock I think this might be helpful to other newbs like me.

Comment: Thanks. I encountered similar error for `appCheck()` on existing codebase, with `__mocks__/firebase-admin.js` set up. So I added the `admin.initializeApp.appCheck` mocking in there.